# Moving to the right Subsubsection in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, amsbook

How the subsubsection head can be moved to the right, e.g. with `5mm`, in the table of contents in `amsbook`  ?
I use the code

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First a couple of comments. (a) If you will be submitting your document to the AMS do not change any of the typesetting. (b) I don't really understand your question; you ask about the ToC but show a desired result in the document body.

The generally accepted method of changing the appearance of ToC entries is to use the `tocloft` package, which doesn't seem to work with the `amsbook` class. Below shows how it can be used with the `book` class to give your desired extra indentation for `subsubsections` in the ToC.

```
% subsubsecprob.tex  SE 567344
%\documentclass{amsbook}
\documentclass{book}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{5mm}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

I have no intention of trying to make `tocloft` compatible with `ams...`, partly because I may not be capable any more, but principally because the AMS have their definite opinions as to how their documents should be typeset. --- GOM

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was trying to code in a book type class.